What's the purpose of this check "!(Account.info.owner == SystemProgram && Account.info.lamports() == 0)" in anchor Account
Account checks that Account.info.owner == T::owner(). This means that the data type that Accounts wraps around (=T) needs to implement the Owner trait. The #[account] attribute implements the Owner trait for a struct using the crate::ID declared by declareId in the same program. It follows that Account can also be used with a T that comes from a different program.
Checks:
Account.info.owner == T::owner()
!(Account.info.owner == SystemProgram && Account.info.lamports() == 0)
what is the meaning of the "!(Account.info.owner == SystemProgram && Account.info.lamports() == 0)" check?

If an account's owner is the system program and it has no lamports in it, then you might be able to assume that the account is unused. This is an account's default state. So if Anchor sees an account with no lamports and owned by the system program, it assumes that the account is not initialized, and returns AccountNotInitialized.
